# Unable to retreive information from API

Tags: api, url, https

I'm trying to retrieve information about SNCF's public API, including the availability of train tickets (and the number available). I rely on the page https://doc.navitia.io/#journeys which gives the procedure to follow to retrieve such information (including the parameters "Fare", "Cost" and "Ticket").
However, when I fill in these parameters on my URL to retrieve API data on a specific route, I don't get any information about the tickets (while checking on the SNCF app I find several tickets). What's the reason for this?
For your information, my URL looks like this:
[https://api.sncf.com/v1/coverage/sncf/journeys?from=admin:fr:75056&to=admin:fr:35238&datetime=20230524T125600&data_freshness=realtime&count=1&depth=3](https://api.sncf.com/v1/coverage/sncf/journeys?from=admin:fr:75056&to=admin:fr:35238&datetime=20230524T125600&data_freshness=realtime&departure?count=1&ticket?cost)

I tried to configure these settings as much as possible, in order to find these information, without success

Thanks for your answers !

Comment: Why does your URL contain _multiple_ `?` ...?

Comment: I apologize, bug when copied the url

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.